# How does CocoaPods add files to a target when they're actually not added as a member of a target?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, pod-install, xcode-build-phase

I'm working with a CocoaPod private library.
We have mock files that are being used for our Swift Previews.

What's surprising is that these mock files aren't added as a member to the pod's target. They're a a member of the *Test* Target. Yet they compile.

I don't understand why/how it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I further inspected the setup I noticed that within the `PodSpec`, for its `source_files` field I saw something like the following:

```
 # mock files are being built into the pod so they can be used for SwiftUI previews
 s.source_files = 'OurCoolPod/**/*.{swift,storyboard}', 'Example/Tests/Mocks/**/*.swift', 'Example/Tests/ManagerMocks/*Mock*.swift', 'Example/Tests/HelpersTestsAndMocks/*Mock*.swift',
```

I believe the source files are added onto the target if either:

- They're from within the above directories. `pod install` later adds them onto the 'Build Phase' of target under 'Compile Sources'
- They're added to the correct target, but isn't added to a `source_files` paths. **ATTENTION:** things work only up until you do a `pod install`. As soon as you do `pod install` it will stop working because `pod install` will remove it from the Build Phase. Hence this isn't something you should do or rely on. I just mentioned it as insight for debugging things.

Tldr the PodSpec will supercede your Xcode configurations because `pod install` overrides things.

**But why is CocoaPods like this?**

I suppose mainly because it wants to have a higher focus on the Swift/Objective-C language and less focus on Xcode.

When you rely on paths instead of a very specific Xcode project file, then other tools like the terminal, vim, VSC can be used a lot easier.

Like you don't need Xcode *running* (you need the Xcode Command Line Tools *installed* though) to execute `pod lib lint`. And this in itself is a great advantage. It simplifies the development process.